# Can not access cells on uitableview's sections which not displaying on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having trouble with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

I have a tableview with multiple sections. All sections have dynamic rows and all rows have some form fields. The last sections row count is increasing or decreasing depending on the form fields of the other sections.

I am accessing the cells of last section with following code:

```
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: remarkCount, inSection: clsections.count )
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! remarkCell!
```

is this sample tableview has 10 sections.

the problem is ;

if the section 10 is visible on iPad's screen (simply scroll down to bottom of tableview), cell will be created as! remarkCell! Otherwise cell will be nil.

Should I programmatically scroll to bottom of tableview before using cellForRowAtIndexPath?  Or is there any alternate methods to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier without re-using cells ?

Thank you.

Comment: Table view cells are just views on to your data.  You should not rely on them to store data; use a data model such as an array for that.  Cells that are not on screen cannot be retrieved.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 , but tableview is a form and  there are user-inputs on those dynamic cells.  I am trying to read these values.

Comment: You need to store that data into a data model somewhere; as soon as those cells scroll out of view they will be reused and the data will be lost. I suggest you set a delegate on your cell back to your view controller and have your cell call a delegate method when the text changes so that you can store the text in order to restore it when the cell is to be displayed again

Answer (score 0):

CellForRowAtIndexPath will be called automatically when needed (when the cell is about to be visible).
When you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, it will "recycle" an existing cell if possible, or create a new one if not

Comment: hi @Roee84 
is there any method which not recycles existing cells ?

Comment: let cell = UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: nil)
just pass nil as the reuseIdentifier